# Google Maps SDK for iOS Preview API Keys

Tags: ios, google-maps

Google says that to be able to use the maps API you need to register for access to an API key and they will contact with us when the api keys are made available. I registered for the key but so far I haven't got anything.

Any idea when those keys are gonna be available..

Thanks

Comment: How much of the API are you trying to use? Some of it is available without a key.

Comment: I'm talking about the new Google Maps SDK for iOS which is released today.. and also I know that the Google Maps URL Scheme can be used without key but that's not what I want

Comment: old and only valid when it was asked (more than a year ago)
confusing & useless now IMO

Answer (score 0):

No idea when licenses might be given out, but please be aware substantial license restrictions exist in the Google Maps SDK:

https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Just 2500 requests per day for both geocoding and directions, also some resolution limitations.

You may well be better off using the iOS mapping framework which has no restrictions.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of request limitation.I checked the website and went over all the details about the API.  I'm not planning publish an app to the app store or something. I just wanted to learn the API and have an experience but without API key can't test the app. Thanks for the  info though.

Comment: Is that limitation per key or per device?

Comment: Per key...  Google wants any high volume users to pay.

Comment: I don't think so. In the FAQ it says: "Which Maps API services are affected by the usage limits? [...] The Google Earth API, and **native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected.**". See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits

Comment: Very interesting, I did not see that before.  It's very confusing as that page totally contradicts the page I found, although I admit it seems more likely Google would not have a limit on the use of the SDK they release.  But the page I linked to does explicitly say "Mobile Apps".

Comment: Well, anyway, I applied for a key a long time ago and still didn't get any response. -_________-

Comment: @Philippe: that's still ambiguous, they may be just talking about the "native" api, meaning, in case of apple iPhone sdk, iOs < 6, when native mapKit framework used googleMap service. But what about the new "Google Maps SDK for iOS" added to be used in iOs 6 (as alternative to native apple maps)? It's not a native API, you have to download it, register and get a key, so, would google consider it as the older API service? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios

Answer (score 0):

You can ***Create new iOS key*** via [APIS console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) following these [instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start). There will be a 40-char API key if successful, maybe you can testrun with this key.

Comment: I already created API key but so far I haven't got any email from them

Comment: I see options for creating Server, Browser, and Android keys. But no option for creating an iOS key. Will that only show up once I've been approved? (I applied weeks ago and still have heard nothing).

Answer (score 0):

i was registered  in getting api key for google ios sdk.i got key after registering 3days .so it will be the issue regarding your id provided or your acceptance  of google terms and conditions.