# creating google api for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

I have registered in (https://developers.google.com/maps/ios-access) `GoogleAPIs` console to get `Apikey` for google maps sdk for `iOS`. but i didnt get and also i didnt find google maps sdk for ios option to enable in `Google API`s console. can any one plz suggest me to get api key

Google maps api key for ios is not visible in API access panel in API project..

Create new iOS key is missing in API Access pane in the console.as per i followed

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: will you please check this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865098/google-maps-sdk-for-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865098/google-maps-sdk-for-ios) the issue is a common one and the only thing you can do is to report to the google, but from my personal experience, i think that too won't make any change! SO, YOU HAVE TO WAIT !

Comment: so sad to know that this question is closed by someone, this is not at all OFF-TOPIC and is a common issue suffered by who all try to use the new google maps api for iOS!

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be off-topic to me, but it is extremely poorly formulated, vague, and incomplete. I believe it should have been closed as Not a Real Question, and I am voting to delete since it hasn't been improved since closure.